# Are CSS Element dimensions in EM still contemporary?

Tags: css, accessibility

I still use EM's in the CSS to specify the sizes of elements in my templates.

Today most browsers are able to correctly scale websites where the sizes are given in PX.

My argument for using EM's was / is: if a person that has a sight disability and changes the base font size in the browser, the design still fits.

I'm asking because for me its still a source of errors to use EM's. When i specify a different font-size then the base font-size on a element, I often forget to adapt my EM calculation for the children elements.

Now i have 2 questions:

1. How do people with a sight
   disability configure the browser (do
   they use the browser zoom or do they
   still change the base font-size)?
2. Does it still make sense to use EM's
       for element sizes nowadays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Based on what I've read, neither. Users with mild-to-moderate sight difficulties often use applications distinct from the UA itself to provide zooming functions. These tools can magnify all or part of a display, but (in my limited experience) they don't zoom the text out-of-relation to the setting.
2. It still makes sense to use 'em'. First of all, accessibility isn't the only reason to use 'ems'. I think the inheritance model of relative sizes makes more sense with ems and percentages than it does with pixels. Second, you can do calculations in CSS3 itself, if it helps you to not need to remember to adapt your calculations.

refs:

- http://www.championinternet.com/rwa/Ann.pdf
- http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-em-rather-than-px
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

Comment: thank you for the links! Hope the calculating is gonna be up and running soon

Answer (score 1):

Physical dimensions (px) are generally worse than logical (pt, em, %) because physical devices' size and resolution may vary wildly (from a small handset to a desktop screen to a wall-mounted plasma screen). Unless you're tightly bound to a piece of raster graphics, there should not be any disadvantage in specifying dimensions in logical units.

If you always specify font sizes as percent of base size, it's harder to forget to use the logical units :) Also a user can just specify base font size in the browser and your entire design adapts automatically.

When font size is too small for me to read, I zoom a little. Also I specify quite large base size for Japanese pages so that I can make out the glyphs. But if a page resists to adapt to font change, I usually just hit my 'Readability' bookmarklet, and the offending design disappears completely.

Comment: this is a good argument. But why are you still changing the font-size, and not the default browser-zoom of the page?

Comment: because it's easier to ctrl+mousewheel than to open settings and change the base font size, basically :) my current base font size is comfortable on 99% of sites, but once in a while I encounter a site with uncomfortably tiny letters, which I have to zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still in favor of using EM as a unit. But like you said, modern browser scales size pretty well even with other units.

I think the most important is to always use the same unit across the website. As long as you don't start to mix different unit, the browser should handle everything well.

The only real advantage I see nowadays to use EM, is that someone who has increased is default font size will see your site with bigger elements without doing anything. If you use PX, the person probably have to change the size manually.

Comment: with one exception: When you have elements that contain sprites in the CSS, you cant use EM as size element. (i know with CSS3 you can :) )